# Mixing pointers and references in function definition in C++

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, reference

I have a function that has two instances of classes as arguments:

```
void cookPasta(const Tomato& tomato, const Meat* meat)
{
    if (meat != nullptr)
        cookPastaWithMeat(tomato, *meat);
    else
        cookPastaWithoutMeat(tomato);
}
```

As the function shows, an instance of `Tomato` is always required, whereas `Meat` is optional and a `nullptr` can be passed instead. I do this to allow the `cookPasta` function to be called even if the user has never declared an instance of the `Meat` class.

Is it bad practice to mix references and pointers in the function signature?

Comment: It might be a bit easier on the  user of your function if both arguments were pointers but then the compiler wouldn't enforce for you that the first argument is non-null.

Comment: @PSkocik. That would include an additional error check in my function. Do you think that is preferable over mixing pointers and references?

Comment: _"I have a function that has two classes as arguments"_ No, you don't.

Comment: @Chiel: I think it's preferable not to mix them, and not to have this function at all. Have two `cookPasta` overloads, one taking tomato and meat and the other just taking tomato. Don't use nullability for flow control.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit. Thanks, what is the danger of using the null pointer for flow control?

Comment: @Chiel: Producing crap code

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Thanks, that was a very helpful answer to my question.

Comment: @Chiel: You're welcome

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The one thing you lose with this approach is the possibility to pass in a temporary `Meat`, as its address can't be taken.

Why not use overloading, by simply renaming `cookPastaWithMeat` and `cookPastaWithoutMeat` ?

```
void cookPasta(const Tomato& tomato, const Meat& meat);
void cookPasta(const Tomato& tomato);
```

Comment: I never trust anonymous meat: too much like a 3am kebab. But a good point.

Comment: @Bathsheba You're a difficult cat :p

Comment: What is in this case the advantage of overloading over the optional argument?

Comment: @Chiel `cookPasta(tomato, Meat{})` will compile. I'd say it also looks a bit more idiomatic, but that may be personal taste.

Comment: This is the good practice approach.

Answer (score 8):

Your Practice is good

- You've used `const` keyword.
- Passing reference
- But, 2nd parameter `pointer` can be little better using `optional parameter feature` of C++. [check out here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3784114/how-to-pass-optional-parameters-to-a-method-in-c).

  ```
  void cookPasta(const Tomato& tomato, Meat* meat = nullptr)
  {
      if (meat != nullptr)
          cookPastaWithMeat(tomato, *meat);
      else
          cookPastaWithoutMeat(tomato);
  }
  ```

Now, Call the same function in both way.

```
cookPasta(tomato); // meat will default to nullptr
cookPasta(tomato, meat);
```

Comment: Except you _can't_ call the same function "in both way" without breaking symmetry. You probably meant `cookPasta(tomato, &meat);`, assuming sensible types at the callsite. Do you see now why this is _not_ good practice?

Answer (score 4):

It's good practice since you have a good reason for doing so: a pointer *can* be `nullptr` whereas a reference must always be passed. You are exploiting this elegantly.

Using `const` means that the function cannot modify the parameters passed from the caller; that's good too.

Comment: It's hardly elegant. You're mixing levels of indirection for objects that, semantically, are both to be treated _as_ their base objects rather than as handles. Symmetry is broken and surprise is generated.

Comment: Symmetry is little more than an idealism irrationally desired by physicists.