# Default value for a reference parameter to a function

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a function that takes two parameters. The first parameter is an int& which the function will set to some "return" value.  The second parameter is a pointer and is optional.  The caller can pass a valid pointer if the caller wishes it to be initialized, and if not the default value is nullptr.

```
void find_lis(uint32_t& count,
              vector<uint32_t>* output = nullptr)
{ }
```

All is well.  However, I want to make the second parameter a reference, and allow caller the same option to provide one or not, what should I use as the default value?

```
void find_lis(uint32_t& count,
              vector<uint32_t>& output = ???)
{ }
```

I tried a few things, but they cause a compiler error.  However, the following at least compiles, but I am not sure if it is right?

```
void find_lis(uint32_t& count,
              vector<uint32_t>& output = *(new vector<uint32_t>()))
{ }
```

In the pointer case, I can easily check if the caller passed in a second parameter by comparing value to nullptr. However, in the reference case, I don't see any such easy check.

Comment: In short there's really no good way to have a default argument for a reference. The way you solve it causes a memory leak every time you call the function without providing a value for that argument.

Comment: You have programmed a memory leak. Try this: `vector<uint32_t> output = some_static_variable`.

Comment: "I an easily check if the caller passed in a second parameter by comparing value to nullptr" -- No, you cannot. There is nothing distinguishing a caller that omits the second argument and a caller that passes in `nullptr` explicitly. It may seem like a technicality, but try to understand this and you'll have an easier time thinking about your reference version.

Comment: Actually, let me rephrase my statement.  "I can easily tell if the caller wants the the function to initialize the output parameter (whether the caller did not provide a second argument or provided a nullptr as the second second argument) by comparing output against nullptr".  That is what I meant.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mixing pointers and references in function definition in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31807775/mixing-pointers-and-references-in-function-definition-in-c)

Answer (score 4):

If the implementation of the function is not overly complex, I would suggest creating two overloaded functions.

```
void find_lis(uint32_t& count)
{
   count = 0; // ???
}

void find_lis(uint32_t& count,
              vector<uint32_t>& output)
{
   // Proper implementation
}
```

Another option:

```
void find_lis(uint32_t& count)
{
   // I'm guessing this will work. May be not.
   static vector<uint32_t> dummy;
   find_lis(count, dummy);
}

void find_lis(uint32_t& count,
              vector<uint32_t>& output)
{
   // Proper implementation
}
```

**Update, in response to comment by OP**

Use:

```
void find_lis_private(uint32_t& count,
                      vector<uint32_t>& output,
                      bool update)
{
   // Proper implementation
}

void find_lis(uint32_t& count)
{
   static vector<uint32_t> dummy;
   find_lis_private(count, dummy, false);
}

void find_lis(uint32_t& count,
              vector<uint32_t>& output)
{
   find_lis_private(count, output, true);
}
```

A better option is to use:

```
template <typename UpdateFunction>
void find_lis_private(uint32_t& count,
                      vector<uint32_t>& output,
                      UpdateFunction fun)
{
   // Proper implementation
   // call fun() with the necessary arguments when it's time
   // to update.
}

void find_lis(uint32_t& count)
{
   static vector<uint32_t> dummy;
   find_lis_private(count, dummy, [](args...) {/* Empty function */});
}

void find_lis(uint32_t& count,
              vector<uint32_t>& output)
{
   find_lis_private(count, output, [=output](args...) {/* Update output */});
}
```

Then, you don't have to use `if`/`else` blocks to update.

Comment: Third option: both overload call the overload with pointer (which may be non public).

Comment: For the first option, I don't think it will work.  find_lis() with one parameter needs to call the other find_lis(), which I am not seeing in the code you provided.  As for the second option, in find_lis() taking two parameters, how would one check if the output parameter is something the caller provided and needs to filled, or a dummy that find_lis can avoid initializing (aka less work to do).

Comment: This might work, but slight correction to your code.  In find_lis() that takes two parameters, you need to call find_lis() with three parameter withe the third argument as "true".  (Or the other find_lis() that takes one argument needs to call with "true"). Both calls to the private function should not be called with same third argument value.

Comment: @Jarod42, That's another possibility. I think a better option is to use `lambda` appropriately.

Comment: In the lambda case, I think we can even get ride of vector reference parameter.

Comment: @Jarod42, Since the OP didn't provide the details of the function implementation, it's hard telling what's the best way to implement the *update* part of the function.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to bind a temporary to an lvalue reference, you can use a helper function to convert the rvalue to an lvalue:

```
template <class T>
T& lvalue_cast(T&& t)
{
    return t;
}

void find_lis(uint32_t& count,
              std::vector<uint32_t>& output = lvalue_cast(std::vector<uint32_t>()))
{
}
```